# Count of sequences of a numbers in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have an array looking like

`[0, 2, 4, 10, 10, 10, 10, 2, 5, 3, 2, 10, 10, 5, 7, 4, 10, 10, 10, 10]`

How can I count the number of times we see a sequence of `10's` if the sequence is at least 3 occurrences.

So in this case the output would be `2` because there are 2 sequecnes of 10's with four 10's in a row each.

```
const values = [0, 2, 4, 10, 10, 10, 10, 2, 5, 3, 2, 10, 10, 5, 7, 4, 10, 10, 10, 10];
const MAX = 10;
const threshold = 3;
let count= 0;

let numberInSeq = 0;

values.forEach(x => {
  if (x === MAX) {
    numberInSeq++;
  } else {
    if (numberInSeq >= threshold) {
      count++
    }
    numberInSeq = 0;
  }
})
return count;
```

This is what I currently have and I believe it should work but I feel like there is a more optimized way to do this.

Thank you!

Comment: What seems non-optimal about that? You have to look through the whole array and count the occurrences one way or another, and that's what your code does.

Comment: http://jsben.ch/bdMGy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some slight errors in your `forEach` loop.  You need to be checking the threshold **if the current value matches the checked value i.e. `MAX` in your case** and then reset the `numberInSeq` if the threshold is met.  This will allow a correct counting of sequences. I also added a flagger variable `sequenceFound` for long sequences so they aren't counted more than once.

The advantage to this method is that it is a single pass through which means in Big O Notation it's only an `O(n)` complexity versus multiple pass through solutions.

```
var sequenceFound = false;

values.forEach(x => {
  if (x === MAX) {
    numberInSeq++;
    if (numberInSeq >= threshold && sequenceFound === false) {
      count++;
      sequenceFound = true;
      numberInSeq = 0;
    }
  } else {
    numberInSeq = 0;
    sequenceFound = false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

***One way of doing*** is joining arr to string with one character and than using regex match `10 followed by that character` and than check the length each match and reduce to a single values

```js
let arr = [0, 2, 4, 10, 10, 10, 10, 2, 5, 3, 2, 10, 10, 5, 7, 4, 10, 10, 10, 10]

let op = arr
        .join('-')
        .match(/(10-)+/g)
        .reduce((o,e)=> (o = e.split('-').length-1 >= 3 ? o+1 : o)  , 0)

console.log(op)
```

***On side note*** - Definitely it will be now where in terms of performance when it comes to using for loop.

Comment: Iterating twice over the array, joining the elements, firing up some regular expression and splitting the matches to then "see" if there's a sequence > 3 is better than a simple loop/`.forEach()`? O.o

Comment: @Andreas ***i said one way of doing***. when it comes to speed than i will go with `for loop` not `foreach` have a look at benchmarks here http://www.jsbenchmarks.com/?anywhichway/loop/master/benchmark.js

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using regex:

> ```
> /, 10{3,}/g
> ```

All the criteria is in that regex, but the array has to converted into a string first. It's different if not as efficient.

### Demo

```js
let val = [0, 2, 4, 10, 10, 10, 10, 2, 5, 3, 2, 10, 10, 5, 7, 4, 10, 10, 10, 10];
let str = val.join(', ');
let i = 0;
const rgx = /(, 10){3,}/g;
let res = rgx.exec(str);
while (res !== null) {
  i++;
  console.log(res[0]);
  res = rgx.exec(str);
}

console.log(`count: ${i}`);
```